# How I can handle Camera, notifications and location alerts(web based) in selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, camera, alert

Its not working with switch and sikuli

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

```
        String photopath= "C:\\Users\\Pictures\\";
        Screen s= new Screen();
        Pattern np = new Pattern("picture\\abc.png");
        try {
            s.click(np);
        } catch (FindFailed e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

[[In sikuli dependency it showing this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIRql.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYIOd.png)

```
Is there any alternative of sikuli or how can it accept normally.[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTwov.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for web based alerts, it really works: [Otherwise, default allow camera from the site setting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91M1a.png)

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    HashMap<String, Integer> contentsettings = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    contentsettings.put("media_stream", 1);
    /*
     * for location : "geolocation" 
     * For camera and microphone : "media_stream" 
     * For notification: "notifications"
     */
    profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentsettings);
    prefs.put("profile", profile);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```